# asp.net how to bind List<model> data to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my linq method it returns List as query result. The model is generated based on the fields of data table. E.G it has three fields model.id, model.name, model.createTime. If I want to use gridview to display returned data which is in List format. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GridView.DataSource = List<Model>
GridView.Databind()
```

You can set the Datasource property to your data and call Databind to update the grid from your data source.

This would be added to your code behind when the population should occur.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx).

Comment: Is this just for .net 4.0? I use .net 3.5

Comment: @Steven Zack you can choose the correct version at the top using the "Other Versions" next to .NET Version 4. Also, look at the page on MSDN it details how to use Templates to alter the data before it goes to the browser.